# Carousel Jquery add previous and next function

Tags: jquery

I have a small jQuery Carousel
HTML

```
<div class="advantages-slider">
<ul class="advantages-list">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$.fn.carousel = function () {
var self = this;

var width = self.find('li').outerWidth(true);
self.find('li:nth-child(2)').addClass('main-item');

setInterval(function () {       

    self.find('li').removeClass('main-item');
    self.find('li:nth-child(3)').addClass('main-item')
        .delay(10000)
        .queue(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('main-item');
        $(this).dequeue();
    });

    var text = self.find('.advantage-item-text').html();

    $('.advantage-full-item .full-item-text').slideUp(1000).empty().html(text).slideDown(1000).delay(8000);

    self.delay(8000).animate({
        right: '+=' + width
    }, {
        duration: 2000,
        queue: false,
        complete: function () {

            var first = self.find('li:first-child');
            first.remove();
            self.append(first);
            self.css({
                right: '-=' + width
            });
        }
    });
}, 10000);

return this;
};

$('.advantages-list').carousel();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8d4Fh/21/

It works automatically. But now I need to add control buttons, when I click on the `prev` button to scroll to the previous one slide back, when I click on the `next` button to scroll forward one slide.
Please show me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are still interested I tried to respond to the question you've posed yesterday.
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/4WL5R/1/)
I modified your css/javascript code for easier click on prev and next buttons.
But the final result is quite similar to your.
 
I also added a countdown to restart the slideshow after ten second (click prev next buttons)
This is just an example if you don't like it, I'm sorry for the inconvenience.

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.fn.carousel = function () {

        var giranews = setInterval(function(){move()},5000);
        var width = $(this).find('li').outerWidth(true); 
        $(this).find('li:nth-child(3)').addClass('main-item');
        var that=$(this);

        function move(){
            var first = that.find('li:first-child');
            first.animate({'margin-left': '-='+width},2000,function(){
                that.append(first);
                that.find('li').removeAttr('style');
                that.find('li:nth-child(3)').addClass('main-item');
                that.find('li:nth-child(2)').removeClass('main-item');
            });
        };

        function stopx(){
               clearInterval(giranews);
        };

        function countdown(a) {
            var count = a;
             timerId = setInterval(function() {
                count--;
                console.log(count);
                if(count == 0) {
                    clearInterval(timerId);
                    giranews = setInterval(function(){move()},5000);
                };
            }, 1000);
        };

        $('.next-button-1').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            stopx();
            if(typeof timerId!=='undefined'){clearInterval(timerId);countdown(10)}else{countdown(10)}
            var first = that.find('li:first-child');
            first.stop().animate({'margin-left': '-='+width},2000,function(){
            that.append(first);
            that.find('li').removeAttr('style');
            that.find('li:nth-child(3)').addClass('main-item');
            that.find('li:nth-child(2)').removeClass('main-item');
           });
        });

        $('.prev-button-1').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            stopx();
            if(typeof timerId!=='undefined'){clearInterval(timerId);countdown(10)}else{countdown(10)}
            var first = that.find('li:first-child');
            var last = that.find('li:last-child');
            first.stop().animate({'margin-left': '+='+width},2000,function(){
            that.prepend(last);
            that.find('li').removeAttr('style');
            that.find('li:nth-child(3)').addClass('main-item');
            that.find('li:nth-child(4)').removeClass('main-item');
            });
        });

    };
</script>
```